# searching multiple keyword and print out matched keyword with several field in logs

Tags: awk, grep, logparser

example log (sample.log)

```
11:00:00 INFO KOREA AAABB DDDRR
11:00:01 INFO SWEDEN TYTY PLO
11:00:02 INFO US OIILL OTLTOL
11:00:03 INFO NORTHKOREA OTL
```

KEYWORDs (multiple)
    "KOREA", "OTL"

What I want as a result

```
11:00:00 KOREA
11:00:02 OTL
11:00:03 KOREA OTL
```

I'm just thinking by using awk fuction.
But I failed....

```
# $val_1 = KOREA
# $val_2 = OTL

# awk /$val_1|$val_2/'print{$1, $val_1, $val_2}' sample.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '
function check(word){
  match($0,word);
  if(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)){
    return substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}}
{
  val=check("KOREA");
  val=val?$1 FS val FS check("OTL"):check("OTL")?$1 FS check("OTL"):check("OTL");
  if(val){
    print val};
  val=""
}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much Ravinder! it works. Can I ask one more thing? If I use 10 keywords, can I just add keywork in your code?

Comment: @user8159259, I had written this for only 2 strings post your example will fine tune code accordingly. Also is there any sequence of strings? or any string could come to any line? Do you want all the 10 strings in a line then want to print it? please do let me know on same.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat infile
11:00:00 INFO KOREA AAABB DDDRR
11:00:01 INFO SWEDEN TYTY PLO
11:00:02 INFO US OIILL OTLTOL
11:00:03 INFO NORTHKOREA OTL

$ awk -v search='KOREA|OTL' '{f=$1; s="";while(match($0,search)){s=(s?s OFS:"") substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}if(s)print f,s}' infile
11:00:00 KOREA
11:00:02 OTL
11:00:03 KOREA OTL
```

Better Readable:

```
awk -v search='KOREA|OTL' '{
            f=$1; 
            s="";
            while(match($0,search))
            {
                s  = (s?s OFS:"") substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
                $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            }
            if(s)
               print f,s
            }
            ' infile
```

Comment: Thanks perfact solution,.

Comment: @user8159259 please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work